# Adding list to an empty bag

Tags: haskell

I am trying to add an unordered list such as `[2,1,5,4,3]` to a bag, which can be treated as an empty list.

Here's my code:

```
module Bags where

import Data.List
import Prelude

-- | Bag datatype
type Bag a = [a]

-- | Empty bag
emptyBag :: Bag a
emptyBag = []

-- | Put all elements from a list into a bag.
listToBag :: Bag a -> [a] -> Bag a
listToBag xs = foldr (\x bag -> bagInsert bag x) emptyBag xs
```

The function which inserts the element into the list is shown below

```
-- | Add an element to a bag.
bagInsert :: Bag a -> a -> Bag a
bagInsert b = (insert (+) emptyBag)
```

However, the `insert` function is for ordered elements. Is there away I could add these elements without rearranging their elements' respective positions within the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can:

```hs
module Bags where

type Bag a = [a]

emptyBag :: Bag a
emptyBag = []

listToBag :: Bag a -> [a] -> Bag a
listToBag = foldr (:)

bagInsert :: Bag a -> a -> Bag a
bagInsert = flip (:)
```

The expression `listToBag emptyBag [2,1,5,4,3]` evaluates to the bag `[2,1,5,4,3]`.